# it is of + noun - What does this OF mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Nina: Ky, look at this photo! It's **of** a dinner my parents went to called 'Dinner in the Sky'.
> Ky: Cool! The restaurant is so high above the ground!

What does this OF a dinner mean? Can I say 'It's a dinner my ...'? Is there any difference if OF added?

[image: screenshot of the dialog]

Comment: The pronoun “it” refers to the photo. “This is a picture of the dinner my parents went to” can be the same as “This is the dinner my parents went to.” if we’re showing the pictures to someone and it’s obvious we’re talking about the content of the photo and not the photo itself.

Comment: Is it just me, or is the use of the word "dinner" very odd in the first line.  The photo isn't a photo of a dinner... its a photo of a (strange) restaurant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does this "Ky, look at this photo! It's of a dinner my parents Ky went to" **tell us**?.

It tells me we say: **A photo of something**.
A photo of you.
A photo of me.
A photo of a dinner.
A photo of a reception

That is how we say what is in a picture in English. We use **photo or picture of X.**